# How to solve Server Error in '/' Application.?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications

I have been trying to access my partner's web application from my computer but this problem keeps showing up.I have tried to convert the web application to an application in IIS,but the problem still persists.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 17:                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 18:                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
Line 19:        <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 20:            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
Line 21:        </authentication>
```

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fas\fas\web.config    Line: 19

Show Additional Configuration Errors:

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fas\fas\web.config line 22)
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fas\fas\web.config line 28)
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fas\fas\web.config line 34)

Comment: You will need to specify a bit more information. Please read the FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The error in your description is really vague. The error is probably in the application's code that running on the server...

Comment: I have added the response given by the server.Sorry for the vague information

Comment: What version of IIS. If it is 7 then converting the IIS website to an application might be a solution. Also, you may be required to use an Intergrated-Mode app pool.

Comment: It is IIS7. How do I configure the intergrated mode?

Comment: Convert C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fas\fas\ to web app?

Comment: Select the directory in IIS and select convert to application. You should make sure afterward it is using the intergraded-mode pipeline.

Comment: I did try to convert it to application,but the problem persists after that.Is there any other settings I must set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem happens because you have another web.config file in a sub directory of the application, and it has the `authentication` element. The `authentication` element can only appear in the root web.config. Please refer to the element documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Under the **Element Information** section it's stated that the **Configurable locations** are *Machine.config, Root-level Web.config, Application-level Web.config*

To solve the problem, you have to do either:

- Remover the child web.config, and leave just the one on the root.
- Or, if the child web.config is essential to your application, remove the whole `authentication` element from it. You may configure your `authentication` only once in the root level web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config is incorrect.

You have something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation>
            <assemblies>
               <add assembly="System.Design, ..."/>
               <!-- many  more -->
               <add assembly="System.Design, ..."/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
```

You need some closing tags:

```
            <assemblies>
               <add assembly="System.Design, ..."/>
               <!-- many  more -->
               <add assembly="System.Design, ..."/>
            </assemblies> <!-- You need this -->
        </compilation>    <!-- and this -->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
```

Comment: I only took part of the codes.The code that was shown here are the parts that caused the error

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code. That would include posting valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was incorrect configuration of Owin

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Must be moved to `Startup.Configuration` where Autofac configuration for Owin happens after this configuration.